# Date fields saving the wrong date from front-end form

Tags: templating, datetime, frontend-form

I have a front-end form with two date fields. After upgrading to Craft 3 and implementing what I believe to be all the changes concerning front-end forms in Craft 3 I am experiencing some odd behavior.

**The odd behavior**

When I enter manually or use jQuery UI Datepicker plugin to enter a desired date into any of the date fields associated with this front-end form (this is the only front-end form on the site currently), the date gets saved one day behind. E.g. if I enter 2018-05-01 it gets saved as 2018-04-30. *However*, if I go to the admin area and add a new block to this matrix field it saves correctly.

**What I changed when upgrading from Craft 2 to 3 is the following:**

```
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
```

to

```
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
```

I also checked and confirmed that I am using the most up-to-date version of jQuery UI to rule out the datepicker as the culprit.

Here is a gist of the form: https://gist.github.com/swthate/08152aefe2c481cd792fc156a9ea1bc6

Note: fields/inputs in question are on line 38 and line 49 of the gist (`lotMixDate` and `lotExpireDate`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include a `timezone` parameter to your form in order to get the correct one.

```
<input type="hidden" name="postDate[timezone]" value="America/Los_Angeles">
```

If you don't include something like this in your frontend chances are high you'll receive the wrong time because it adds/subtracts a certain amount of hours. As soon as you include a valid [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php) it will calculate the correct time. Otherwise it will be set to the default system timezone which may differ from your local

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. However, I am getting an array to string conversion error. I'm not sure why, because I confirmed that I am using the same hidden input form as the same field in the back-end:

`<input type="hidden" name="fields[scriptLots][new1][fields][lotExpireDate][timezone]" value="America/Chicago">`

Comment: Did you include your `date` parameter into the array as well? `fields[scriptLots][new1][fields][lotExpireDate][date]` Can you eventually show me the file and line number of the error? Another approach is to include the timezone into the string. Here is the rule https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/DateTimeHelper.php#L173

Comment: Yep, I did add [date] to the end of the actual date input. The line that the error highlights at the top of the stack is line 171 of the file you linked to.

Comment: That means your submitted value is not an array. There must be something wrong with your HTML

Comment: Weird. The `$_POST` dump at the bottom of the error looks correct, to my nooby eyes. Here's a full shot of the error page: https://prnt.sc/jch5gc

Comment: The issue is your `postDate` it's missing it's value and has only a timezone.. Add a valid `date` or remove the `timezone`

Comment: Sorry... There was a second date field I didn't make the same changes to. *facepalm* It's working great now! Thanks, @robin!!

Comment: Okay, something weird is happening, sorry. Both date fields, despite what date is entered, are saving today's date. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I can't provide any help without knowing your `$_POST` parameters. All formats and syntaxes work fine on my end. But I don't rely on jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76891/discussion-between-steven-thate-and-robin-schambach).